# Change one element of column heading in CSV using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have created a CSV file which looks like this:

> RigName,Date,DrillingMiles,TrippingMiles,CasingMiles,LinerMiles,JarringMiles,TotalMiles,Comments
> 0,08 July 2021,19.21,63.05,43.16,45.41,8.52,0,"Tested all totals. Edge cases for multiple clicks.
> "
> 1,09 July 2021,19.21,63.05,43.16,45.41,8.52,0,"Test entry#2.
> "

I wish to change the 'RigName' to something the user inputs. I have tried various ways of changing the word 'RigName' to user input. One of them is this:

```
df= pd.read_csv('ton_miles_record.csv')
user_input = 'Rig805'
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('RigName', user_input)
df.to_csv('new_csv.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

However no matter what I do, the result in the csv file always comes to this:

> Unnamed:0,Date,DrillingMiles,TrippingMiles,CasingMiles,LinerMiles,JarringMiles,TotalMiles,Comments

Why am I getting 'Unnamed: 0' instead of the user input value?

Also, is there a way to change 'RigName' to something else by calling its position? To make multiple changes to any word in its position in future?

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please [state unmistakably, in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): Do you want to change the column name, particular values in that column, or all of the values (`make multiple changes to any word in its position`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
Zubin, you would need to change the column name be looking at the columns as a list.  The code below should do the trick. Also, the same code shows how to access the column by position...  

import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv('ton_miles_record.csv')
user_input = 'Rig805'
df.columns.values[0] = user_input
df.to_csv('new_csv.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you! After 3 hours of trial and error (and a lot of searching), I solved it by doing something similar to your solution.

df= pd.read_csv('ton_miles_record.csv')
user_input = 'SD555'
df.rename(columns={ df.columns[1]: user_input}, inplace=True)
df.to_csv('new_csv.csv', index=False)

Answer (score 0):

After 3 hours of trial and error (and a lot of searching in vain), I solved it by doing this:

```
df= pd.read_csv('ton_miles_record.csv') 
user_input = 'SD555' 
df.rename(columns={ df.columns[1]: user_input}, inplace=True) 
df.to_csv('new_csv.csv', index=False)
```

I hope this helps someone else struggling as I was.